# exercise on $ L(0,1) $ and functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

how could i prove that

$ u_{k}(x)=sin(kx) \to 0 $ as $x\to \infty$ in $ L^{2}(0,1) $

how could i prove that for fixed a,b  real numbers and $ 0 < \lambda <1 $ and for the function defined as

$ u_{k}(x)=  a $  iff $ j/k\le x < (j+\lambda)/k $

$ u_{k}(x) = b$  iff $ (j+\lambda)/k \le x < (j+1)/k $

with $ j=0,1,2,3,....,k-1 $

i must prove that $ u_{k}(x) \to  \lambda a (1-\lambda )b $ as $ k\to \infty $ in $L^{2}(0,1) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** in both cases, show that the involved sequence is bounded in $L^2$ and that 
$$\int_{[0,1]} u_k(x) g(x)\mathrm dx\to \int_{[0,1]} u(x) g(x)\mathrm dx$$
for each smooth function $g$, where $u$ is the wanted weak limit.